# Connect to two different HDFS servers with different usernames in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

Is there any way to get data from HDFS (e.g. with sc.textFile) with two separate usernames in the same Spark job?  For instance, if I have a file on hdfs-server-1.com and the alice user has permission to view it, and I have a file on hdfs-server-2.com and the bob user has permission to view it, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
val rdd1 = sc.textFile("hdfs://hdfs-server-1.com:9000/file.txt", user="alice")
val rdd2 = sc.textFile("hdfs://hdfs-server-2.com:9000/file.txt", user="bob")
```

Is there any way to do something like this?  Or can Spark only connect to HDFS with the same username that it's running as?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (and I've tried this in the past, with Spark 1.4.0), this isn't possible: By default, Spark uses the user running the driver process for accessing HDFS. User can be overridden using the `HADOOP_USER_NAME` VM option when running the driver application (e.g. `-DHADOOP_USER_NAME=alice`). This option is read when constructing the SparkContext, so it can't be changed afterwards.